# which type of argument I can pass into ToIntFunction Functional Interface in JAVA 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

```
ToIntFunction<String> i = (x)-> Integer.parseInt(x);
System.out.println(i.applyAsInt("21235"));
```

Above is the one example for TointFunction where T is Type String.
What other types that I can pass into it as by definition it accepts Generic Type `T`.

Any other example for same with other types except String.

Comment: Your first line of code isn't compilable. `Integer.parseInt` accepts only string arg. You can't pass a generic arg `x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functional interface `ToIntFunction<T>` is just an interface without any implementation. The `T` type shall be substituted with any type for what you implement this interface. You can't use the only implementation for all the range of objects of the various and unknown types.

This is applicable for the String, as you have defined:

```
ToIntFunction<String> i = (x) -> Integer.parseInt(x);
```

You have substituted `T` with `String`, the function excepts `String` with no discussion and returns `Integer`. If you want to have the same function for another type, implement it:

```
ToIntFunction<List<?>> i1  = list -> list.size();                  // A primitive example:
i1.applyAsInt(new ArrayList<>());                                  // gets size of any List

ToIntFunction<MyObject> i2 = myObject -> myObject.getNumber();     // A custom object
i2.applyAsInt(new MyObject());
```

The point is, any type could be substituted with one simple rule: the implementation must assure the `Integer` as a result in any case.

Answer (score 2):

`ToIntFunction<T>` is a Functional Interface which helps you convert an object of type `T` to an `int`.

**Note** that you have to provide definition as to how to convert the type `T` to `int`.

In your example, you have used `T` as `String` and provided a mechanism to convert `string` to `int` via the following method.

```
ToIntFunction<String> i  = (x)-> Integer.parseInt(x);
```

Hence, it works for "21235". But, it'll break for anything other that what `Integer.parseInt(x)` can NOT parse.

If you want to parse a different object to `int`, you'll have to write an appropriate `ToIntFunction` function. Below is an example of converting a custom type class `MyClass` to `int`.

```
class MyClass{ public String num;}
ToIntFunction<MyClass> i = (x1)-> Integer.parseInt(x1.num);
```

Now, the above `ToIntFunction` will work for an object of type `MyClass`.

Comment: What I am asking is other example for ToIntFunction<T> . What others types I can pass and use it to get Int value ?

Comment: @MaksForJava did it answer your question now?

Comment: Yes It is.Thanks but have one more doubt . What other type of variables  i can use apart from String Type (Sting num). Can i use any other type like Long,Double,Float or any primitive Type ?

Comment: You can use anything as long as you provide a function to convert it into int

Answer (score 0):

When using `ToIntFunction<T>` as the target type it means any lambda/function on the right side of the assignment operator must be something that consumes a type `T` and that it returns `int` and it doesn’t matter what type of logic that lambda or custom function does.

In this specific example, as you’re using `Integer.parseInt(...)` on the right side of the assignment operator then the only type `T` can be in order to make the code compile and work is `String`.